# How to close the gap between two rotated rectangles forming a V?

Tags: html, css

So there are these two rotated rectangles forming a V:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Now how to close the gap between them? First I thought the key would be `transform-origin`. But no matter what is set there, it doesn't result in a isosceles V without a gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're already using transforms, you could add a translate to each and just offset them till they cross over

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(0.523em) rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 6.25rem;
  background: blue;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-0.53rem) rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 6.25rem;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But how to achieve exact results when using relative units instead of `px`?

Comment: @Fred Which relative unit specifically? `em` or `rem` should end up at the same result but viewport units would probably be trickier.

Comment: `em` and `rem` are good enough. If you give one of the pseudo classes another color you'll see that the bars seem not to match exactly.

Comment: @Fred See update. I added a border to try and hide what little pixelation was showing and adjusted the values till I couldn't see it anymore. I think I got it as close as I could possibly get. If you zoom in you can't see it but if you're at 100% it almost looks like it's still there but that could be from me starring at it for so long

Comment: Thank you very much! :) By the way, did you see my own answer which I deleted again, where I also used red color for the right bar, or is it just coincidence?

Answer (score 2):

You have to update transform-origin like below. You don't need to consider `bottom` but a slightly upper than bottom (`100% - 10px`). `10px` is half the width

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
}
div::before,
div::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% calc(100% - 10px);
  background: red;
}

div::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```